# How can I disable/uninstall keychain access?

Tags: macos, keychain

I don't want to use keychain access or any password managers for that matter. This is my first mac and I am completely stumped at this supposedly simple task.

My keychain access is not linked to iCloud as in the iCloud setting it's unticked. If I delete everything inside it, the moment I log into anything it starts storing them.

Please just tell me how to stop using keychain access. How can I disable or unistall it permanently.

Edit : I don't want keychain or any program to manage my passords, keychain is automatically storing all my credential without asking for any permission. How can I stop using it completely?

Edit : No I can't just ignore it as it is storing passwords without asking for permissions and blocking me out from using multiple account on same service. This is outright shady, unethical and infuriating and there seems to be no solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129531/discussion-on-question-by-sahil-singh-how-can-i-disable-uninstall-keychain-acces).

Answer (score 1):

You can let it do its thing and just ignore it.

You don't have to accept to save passwords there. But whether you choose to interact with it directly , or not, leave it alone.

Comment: It's storing password without asking me, I don't want that to happen. How can I stop this. I can't ignore it because its blocking my work as I can't have two GitHub account as it can only store one and I have to manually delete the key associated with GitHub to use another account, it's infuriating and downright shady and unethical that apple is forcing this software on me.

Comment: Do your Git Accounts use the same email / ID? Perhaps you need to consider that.

Comment: No they don't, they use different email id and passwords.

Comment: Keychain Access is not stopping you from having more than one Github login, or more than one anything else.  If you actually provide details about what is occurring, someone can tell you what's going on.

Comment: Keychain access is stopping me. If I go and delete the key associated with GitHub on the keychain and then login with another GitHub account it works but now keychain has this account and won't allow the other account to work. Now again you have to delete the current account from keychain and login again with the account you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot uninstall it, it's part of the system and lots of services and apps rely on it. It not only stores passwords, but also certificates, keys and other information that needs to be stored securely. The `Keychain Access.app` is merely a UI to access the keychain service; apps and services use dedicated APIs and for the shell, there's the `security` command. So even if you could remove `Keychain Access` (the app), the service wouldn't be affected. If you were to remove the service, lots of apps and system functionality would break.

Just don't agree to store your password whenever you are asked.

Comment: But it is storing password without asking for permission.

Comment: @SahilSingh: Which app is doing this? The keychain cannot operate on its own, it's always an app that is storing the passwords. Is it Safari? Then disable AutoFill: open the Safari settings, go to the "AutoFill" tab and uncheck "User names and password".

Comment: Why would they make it so that a password manager becomes integral to the system with user having no say in it. I seriously regret having a Mac, such an expensive brick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going on about, a Windows box saves passwords and other credentials, and it's a lot harder to figure out where it might have saved them.

Comment: @DarkDust Any IDE where I am using my GitHub account for example VSCode.  I want to set up two accounts in my vscode but keychain will store info for only one account and block  everything from the other account. I have to manually delete the associated key everytime I want to switch account

Comment: @SahilSingh: A) You do have a say and I'm trying to point you to the right direction. B) Your ranting is not helping. C) Make sure you do not run into a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and really tell us what you _actual_ problem is. If you do not want _Safari_ to store your passwords (which it sounds like you actually want to solve), tell us. If you want to work with multiple GitHub accounts, tell us. Both are only _indirectly_ related to the keychain.

Comment: I want to use multiple GitHub accounts. I am not using Safari at all, I thought I had mentioned that.                                  @Marc Wilson I am not facing any issues with windows.

Comment: @SahilSingh: No, you did not tell us. With which _app_ are you using GitHub. That is the most important part. At this point, it might be a good idea to delete this question and create a new question, _"How to use multiple GitHub account in <some app>"_ to get a good solution to your actual problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter which app I use. Any ide I use the same problem persists. And I did told which app in this comment chain only, I did explicitly mentioned VS Code

Comment: @SahilSingh: It does matter as it is an **app** that is storing the passwords in the keychain **service**. The keychain cannot operate on its own. I repeat, it's important: they keychain does not store passwords on its own, it is always a specific app that does this, and that needs to ask you wether you want to do this. You need to tell the **app** to handle it correctly, not the keychain! So ask: _"How do I handle multiple GitHub accounts in VS Code?"_